# MongoDB return fields after group aggregation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

What I assumed would be a pretty trivial query, turned out to be difficult for me.

I have a collection of event data for users to a website. I am trying to find the landing page for each user. Unique users have the field `anonymousId` and the users current page path is in the nested field `context.page.path`.

I can find the first date which the user visits but am unsure how to extract the `context.page.path` that goes along with that date in the same query. I used the `$first` operator on the page path as well, but I'm fairly certain this is incorrect...

Here is the code I'm using to create the cursor in Python (pymongo):

```
cursor = db.events.aggregate({ 
    '$group':
    { 
        '_id': '$anonymousId',
        'date': { '$first': '$timestamp' },
        'page': { '$first': '$context.page.path' }
    } 
})
```

**Edit:**

Here is the document structure for this collection (redacted)...

```
{
    "anonymousId": "...",
    "timestamp": "2016-04-05T13:05:06.076Z",
    "context": {
        "page": {
            "path": "...",
            "referrer": "...",
            "title": "...",
            "url": "..."
        }
    },
    ... more fields here but not relevant to this question
}
```

Comment: if you could add document structure - then will be easier to solve the issue

Comment: @profesor79 added, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out... but I'm still not 100% positive.

```
cursor = db.events.aggregate([
{ 
    '$group':
    { 
        '_id': '$anonymousId',
        'date': { '$first': '$timestamp' },
        'page': { '$push': '$context.page.path' }
    }
},
{ 
    '$unwind': '$page' 
}
])
```

forgive the poor indentation...